# How can I resize an image in Java on Heroku?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, heroku, image-resizing

I'm running a Play Framework 2 web app on Heroku, and I need to create thumbnails when users upload images, before saving them to the Amazon s3 cloud.  What is the best way to do this?

Note: I am already saving images to s3.  I just need to know how to create the thumbnails first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using http://www.blitline.com/.  It's a cloud based image processor, and they have a good free plan and reasonable prices after that.  They even store my images in s3 for me after they are processed.